# make collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status error

Tags: makefile, arm, hex, cygwin

I have this makefile and when I compile with make cygwin it says:
make: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

```
######################################
# target
######################################
TARGET = blinkingled


######################################
# building variables
######################################
# debug build?
#DEBUG = 1
# optimization
OPT = -Og


#######################################
# paths
#######################################
# Build path
BUILD_DIR = build

######################################
# source
######################################
# C sources
SRCS      = main_cm0plus.c
SRCS      += system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.c
SRCS      += startup.c
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/adc/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/canfd/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/cpu/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/crypto/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/dma/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/evtgen/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/flash/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/gpio/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/ipc/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/lin/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/lvd/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/mcwdt/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/mpu/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/prot/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/scb/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/smartio/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/srom/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/sysclk/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/sysflt/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/sysint/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/syslib/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/syspm/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/sysreset/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/sysrtc/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/systick/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/syswdt/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/tcpwm/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/trigmux/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/interrupts/rev_d/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/mw/button/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/mw/flash/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/semihosting/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/swtimer/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/startup/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/system/*.c)

# ASM sources
ASM_SOURCES =  "C:/data/traveo/TVII_Sample_Driver_Library_7.1.0/tviibe1m/src/startup_cm0plus.s"
#startup_cm0plus.s 


#######################################
# binaries
#######################################
PREFIX = arm-none-eabi-
# The gcc compiler bin path can be either defined in make command via GCC_PATH variable (> make GCC_PATH=xxx)
# either it can be added to the PATH environment variable.
ifdef GCC_PATH
CC = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)size
else
CC = $(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(PREFIX)size
endif
HEX = $(CP) -O ihex
BIN = $(CP) -O binary -S
 
#######################################
# CFLAGS
#######################################
# cpu
CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m0plus

# fpu
FPU = -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16

# float-abi
FLOAT-ABI = -mfloat-abi=soft

# mcu
MCU = $(CPU) -mthumb $(FPU) $(FLOAT-ABI)

# macros for gcc
# AS defines
AS_DEFS = 

# C defines
#C_DEFS = ../../


# AS includes
AS_INCLUDES = 

# C includes

INCDIRS = ../../common/hdr
INCDIRS += ../../common/hdr/cmsis/include
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/drivers
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/drivers/sysclk
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/drivers/flash
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/drivers/syslib
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/drivers/mcwdt
INCDIRS += ../../tviibe1m/hdr/rev_d
INCDIRS += ../../tviibe1m/hdr/rev_d/ip
INCDIRS += ../../tviibe1m/src/system/rev_d
INCDIRS += ../../tviibe1m/hdr/rev_d/mcureg
INCDIRS += ../../tviibe1m/src/drivers/
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/drivers/syswdt
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/mw

INCLUDE   = $(addprefix -I,$(INCDIRS))

# compile gcc flags
ASFLAGS = $(MCU) $(AS_DEFS) $(AS_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

CFLAGS = $(MCU) $(C_DEFS) $(C_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
CFLAGS += -g -gdwarf-2
endif

# My C flags:
CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-variable

# Generate dependency information
CFLAGS += -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"


#######################################
# LDFLAGS
#######################################
# link script
LDSCRIPT = "c:/data/traveo/TVII_Sample_Driver_Library_7.1.0/tviibe1m/src/linker.ld"

# libraries
LIBS = -lc -lm -lnosys 
LIBDIR = 
LDFLAGS = $(MCU) -specs=nano.specs -T$(LDSCRIPT) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections

# default action: build all


all: $(TARGET)
blinkingled: main_cm0plus.o system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.o startup.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
    
    
main_cm0plus.o: main_cm0plus.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main_cm0plus.c
    
system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.o: system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.c cy_project.h cy_device_headers.h 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.c
    
    
startup.o: startup.c startup_customize.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) startup.c
    
BIN_NAME  = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR), $(TARGET))

.PHONY: all
all: $(BIN_NAME).elf
all: $(BIN_NAME).bin
all: $(BIN_NAME).s19
all: $(BIN_NAME).hex
all: $(BIN_NAME).lst
all: print_size


%.bin: %.elf
    $(CP) -O binary -S $< $@

%.s19: %.elf
    $(CP) -O srec -S $< $@

%.hex: %.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex -S $< $@

%.lst: %.elf
    $(CP) -d $< > $@

.PHONY: print_size
print_size: $(BIN_NAME).elf
    $(SIZE) $<



#######################################
# build the application
#######################################
# list of objects
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)))
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(C_SOURCES)))
# list of ASM program objects
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(ASM_SOURCES:.s=.o)))
vpath %.s $(sort $(dir $(ASM_SOURCES)))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c makefile | $(BUILD_DIR) 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.s makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(AS) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) makefile
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(SZ) $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.hex: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(HEX) $< $@
    
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.bin: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(BIN) $< $@    
    
$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir $@        

#######################################
# clean up
#######################################
clean:
    -rm -fR $(BUILD_DIR)
  
#######################################
# dependencies
#######################################
-include $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.d)

# *** EOF ***
```

error:

```
c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-no
ne-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v6-m/nofp\libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): in function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x18): undefined reference to `_exit'
c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccHNkyd5.o: in function `main':
main_cm0plus.c:(.text.main+0x2): undefined reference to `SystemInit'
c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: main_cm0plus.c:(.text.main+0xa): undefined reference to `Cy_SysEn
ableApplCore'
c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: main_cm0plus.c:(.text.main+0x14): undefined reference to `Cy_GPIO
_Pin_Init'
c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: main_cm0plus.c:(.text.main+0x1a): undefined reference to `Cy_SysT
ick_DelayInUs'
c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: main_cm0plus.c:(.text.main+0x28): undefined reference to `__cm4_v
ector_base_linker_symbol'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:173: main_cm0plus.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?
I am trying to generate a hex and elf from this makefile.
Also, I would appreciate any tips/corrections on my makefile. I am trying to blink a led but im very new to arm development with makefiles
thanks

Comment: Well, your Makefile clearly has no rule for which `blinkingled` matches. This is exactly what the error message tells you.

Comment: how can I solve this please? what should I add

Comment: Probably, instead of target `blink` it should be `blinkingled`: this is what the corresponded command **actually** produces (in accordance to `-o blinkingled` parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
all: blinkingled

blink: main_cm0plus.o system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.o startup.o
        $(CC) main_cm0plus.o system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.o startup.o -o blinkingled
```

Here you have two rules that define two targets: the `all` target depends on a prerequisite `blinkingled` and the `blink` target which depends on a bunch of object files.

When make invokes the `blink` target, it actually creates a file named `blinkingled`.  This is wrong.  Make only knows what you told it in the makefile, it has no way to know that you lied to it about what your recipe will do.  If you define rule with a target named `blink`, then make believes you that the recipe you provided it will create a target named `blink`.

You need to change your recipe so that you are telling the truth to make and make the target match the file that is built:

```
blinkingled: main_cm0plus.o system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.o startup.o
        $(CC) main_cm0plus.o system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.o startup.o -o blinkingled
```

Now everything will work.

Even better is to use make's [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) in your recipe, so you KNOW that you're creating the targets make expects (plus, DRY is a great principle for programming):

```
blinkingled: main_cm0plus.o system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.o startup.o
        $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I now have another error collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Do you have an idea where the problem is please? thanks

Comment: That message is just telling you that the link failed.  The important things are the error messages that were printed before this line.  Once you fix those, then this error will go away.  This is a completely separate problem and you should ask a completely separate question, with all details available, rather than updating this question: in particular, please be sure to show the command line that make invoked that caused the errors; the errors you show look weird because they're from the _linker_, but make says it's trying to create `main_cm0plus.o` which is an _object_ file.

Comment: When you ask your other question, be sure to show the parts of the makefile around line 173, since that's where make says the rule is that causes this problem.